# Can I sync the to do list in Microsoft Entourage to an iPod touch?

Tags: ipod-touch, ms-office

Is it possible to sync the to do list in Entourage to an iPod touch. My Dad has his whole to do list in Entourage and would like to sync it with his iPod touch. How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be possible. The to-do list would be considered 'tasks', which falls under the category of Calendar Events.

in Entourage, choose **Entourage** > **Preferences** and click **Sync Services** under **General Preferences**:

[image: Entourage Sync]

---

More information: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1670

Comment: Where would those tasks show up on the iPod touch?

Comment: @daviesgeek — They should show up in the Reminders or Calendar on the iPod.

Comment: @daviesgeek, let me know how it worked out.

Comment: I will let you know.